# App is not using custom theme

Tags: android

i want to disable the ActionBar in my application, I have been looking for a solution on stackoverflow for quiet a while but nothing helped. My problem is that my custom-theme "NoActionBar" is not used, instead it keeps using "AppBaseTheme" although I changed it in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
```

values-v14 styles:

```
<resources>
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

same with values-v11. In values i added this line but I think its not neccessary:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

I tried to change the parent of NoActionBar, didn't work. I tried to create an extra .xml for "NoActionBar" but that didn't work either because the manifest didn't find it. I tried other tipps from stackoverflow questions but they're pretty outdated.
I know when i put the two "items" within the "AppBaseTheme"-style it works, but I'm pretty sure that is not the proper way to use it?

**In a nutshell:**
Can somebody please explain to me why its not using my theme? What theme needs which parent? (How would I define multiple themes?)

I hope I explained it properly, I assume the answer is rather simple, sorry in advance for my language mistakes, I'm not native. Thanks!

**Edit Manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your theme but your parent can't be AppBaseTheme, you have to use as parent for example Theme.Holo.NoActionBar or at least a style without action bar.

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought this could be the problem but what if another Theme needs the ActionBar and the BaseTheme has none?

Comment: @somecreativeusername You need just to create another theme with the correct parent and specify this theme with android:theme property in the activity section of your manifest, for each activity you need to use it.